# Implement advisory lock inside stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

I have a `stored procedure` shown below which is running every *15 minutes* trigged from postgres `cron`. Usually it happens that this *procedure* needs more time to finish. In such situation when next schedule is achieved and procedure is called again I would like procedure to be still called but wait till previous is finished. How can I achieve that without losing any new procedure call? I've heard that this can be achieved by using `advisory lock` nevertheless i am not sure how should I prepare my *procedure* to implement such feature. Can anyone show how exactly could i prepare my procedure?

**My stored procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test_procedure(p1 integer,
 INOUT p2 character varying)

 LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $procedure$

DECLARE

  loop_var int;

BEGIN


  IF p1 is null OR p2 is null THEN

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'input cannot be null';

  END IF;

  DROP TABLE if exists test_table;

  CREATE TEMP TABLE test_table(a int, b varchar);

    FOR loop_var IN 1..p1 LOOP

        insert into test_table values (loop_var, p2);

        p2 := p2 || '+' || p2;

    END LOOP;


END;

$procedure$
```

**Procedure after modification:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.test_procedure(p1 integer,
 INOUT p2 character varying)

 LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $procedure$

DECLARE

  loop_var int;

BEGIN
  SELECT pg_advisory_lock(4711);
  IF p1 is null OR p2 is null THEN

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'input cannot be null';

  END IF;

  DROP TABLE if exists test_table;

  CREATE TEMP TABLE test_table(a int, b varchar);

    FOR loop_var IN 1..p1 LOOP

        insert into test_table values (loop_var, p2);

        p2 := p2 || '+' || p2;

    END LOOP;
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(4711);
END;

$procedure$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS):

At the beginning of the procedure, take an exclusive advisory lock:

```
PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(4711);
```

Immediately before the end, release the lock:

```
PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(4711);
```

The number 4711 is a random number, all that counts is that you don't use the same advisory lock number anywhere else.

Then the second concurrent execution of the function will block when it tries to take the advisory lock and will only be allowed to continue when the lock is released.

Comment: so i can tread this 4711 as static value? Moreover if the next call of procedure is triggered that will makes new call like in await mode but still will be executed once previous is done a, i tight?

Comment: Yes, 4711 is a constant. If you need the same kind of serialization for a different function/procedure, you'd use a different number (a different advisory lock) there. I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: @La  Look at my main post i've updated proceudre in section: "Procedure after modification". Now what i wrote is having that modified procedure scheduled in cron every 15 minutes. Let's suppose procedure runs > 15 minutes. Cron calls same procedure again meantime as 15 minutes reached. What will happen in this case - If I understood well the next call of same procedure will wait till previous running one is finished but will still start the second procedure call? Am I right?

Comment: Correct. Your modified procedure should be fine.

Comment: but is it true what i've asked in second sentence that if procedure is alrady running and when cron reaches next schedule the new procedure call will be awaiting and will still execute once previous run will finish or it will be discarded?

Comment: Yes. The function will begin running, but execution will be suspended at the point where you take the lock.

Comment: ok thats great cause i thought when it reachs new cron trigger the new call will be canceled if that procedure is already running but since u said it will be just suspended but still run thats very good. Thanks. I mark ur post as an answer. P.S Just one more last question: lets assume procedure is running and next call is suspended (waiting the previous to accomplish) what if also another next trigger will come and we already have one procedure suspended awaiting. WIll also 3rd trigger call be suspended etc... ?

Comment: Yes, that's how locks work. If the first one releases the lock, one of the others will grab it.

Comment: when i putted that code i am getting now error: ERR-42601: query has no destination for result data. Should i just replace SELECT to PERFORM instead so by means as follows?:  PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(4711);   PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(4711); P.S What exactly is the diffrence when i use advisory lock and when not? If not mistaken if i would not explicitly add it to code some lock anyway would be added so why to use advisory lock explicitly, whats the diff?

Comment: Yes, it should be `PERFORM`; I have fixed the answer. Sorry, but you won't get a tutorial here.

Comment: If I have two different procedures which run for the same PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(ID) and ID is the same in these two different procedures, so will these two procedures wait for each other?

Comment: @VasoMiruashvili I don't think so.